# SEO: Multilingual website with different subdirectories for each languages

Tags: seo, url, multilingual

I have a multilingual website with the following structure:

```
example.com       <--- Main english version
example.com/fr    <--- The french version
```

Is it important for SEO reasons to put a trailing slash in `example.com/fr` and make it `example.com/fr/` or is it not important?

Comment: Sorry, this question has been asked [many times in various forms](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=trailing%20is%3aquestion) and therefore has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

The final slash will not have any impact on the SEO strategy. 
Just make sure you are not generating duplicate content ([use only one version](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066)) and implement [hreflang](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077) tag.